# WooCommerce print subcategory of product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using Wordpress with Woocommerce, I am on the detail page of the product content-product-single.php.

I created several "sub" and I have to print ONLY subcategories associated with that product.

I am using this code:

```
$categories = array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'child_of' => 1,
        'parent' => '8',
        'orderby' => 'term_group',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'hierarchical' = > 1,
        'exclude' => '',
        'property' => '',
        'number' => '',
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'pad_counts' => false);

$cats = get_categories ($categories);
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    echo '<a <br/> href="'. get_term_link($cat-> slug,' product_cat ').' "> '. $cat-> name.'</a>';
}
```

Where 'parent' => '8' is the 'id of my categories FATHER

But this code  print ALL subcategories that are not empty, I am interested in only those instead of THIS PRODUCT.

Thanks and good luck

Comment: Maybe my answer to [Display product child categories from specific parent](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116787/22534) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Configure, product_id and parent_category_id according to your requirements.

```
/* This is product id */
$product_id = 1;
/* This is the id of the parent category */
$parent_category_id = 8;

$cats = get_categories ( array (
    'type' => 'product',
    'parent' => $parent_category_id,
    'orderby' => 'term_group',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'hierarchical' = > 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'property' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'pad_counts' => false
));

$non_empty_sub_categories_ids = array_map(create_function('$cat', 'return $cat->term_id;'), $cats);

$product_cats = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($product_cats as $product_cat) {
    if(in_array($product_cat->term_id, $non_empty_sub_categories_ids)) {
        echo '<a <br/> href="'. get_term_link($product_cat->slug,' product_cat ').' "> '. $product_cat->name.'</a>';        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'slug' => array('category_slug'),
    'hide_empty' => true
);
$product_cat = get_terms( $args );
foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat){
echo '<ul> 
        <li><a href="'.get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$parent_product_cat->name.'</a>
            <ul> ';
                $child_args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'hide_empty' => true,
                    'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
                );
                $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
                foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</a></li>';
                }
    echo '  </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>';
}
```

?>

Comment: Try to include some explanation in your answer as to why/how this solves the OP's issue.